# Least square fit a 2D line

Tags: python, least-squares

I realize I could use numpy to find the line like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,6,7])
b = np.array([5,4,3,2,-2,-1])
k,m = np.polyfit(a,b,1)
plt.scatter(a,b)
plt.plot([0,10],[m,10*k+m])
plt.show()
```

[image]

but I'd like to use raw python code instead. My math is too rusty, but if can be done in a few lines of code I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. What exactly do you mean by raw Python code? You can quickly find the equations for the ordinary least squares coefficient estimates. They would be pretty straightforward to implement, although, it wouldn't neatly fit into "a few lines" without using `numpy`/`scipy` matrix algebra routines.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: A numpy matrix algebra implementation is definitely good enough (but I'm not able to figure it out myself)!

Comment: I'm on my phone, but check [this out](https://www.google.com/amp/s/thetarzan.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/calculate-ols-regression-manually-in-python-using-numpy/amp/)

Comment: And [here](https://medium.com/@dhwajraj/python-regression-analysis-part-3-ordinary-least-squares-d419322c8da2) is the simple 2 dimensional case. No matrix algebra needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) based on minimizing the quadratic error, the pure Python implementation is pretty straightforward (check equations for α and β on the link above):

```
def linear_fit(x, y):
    """For set of points `(xi, yi)`, return linear polynomial `f(x) = k*x + m` that
    minimizes the sum of quadratic errors.
    """
    meanx = sum(x) / len(x)
    meany = sum(y) / len(y)
    k = sum((xi-meanx)*(yi-meany) for xi,yi in zip(x,y)) / sum((xi-meanx)**2 for xi in x)
    m = meany - k*meanx
    return k, m
```

For your sample input:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,6,7]
>>> y = [5,4,3,2,-2,-1]
>>> linear_fit(x, y)
(-1.1614906832298135, 6.285714285714285)
```